# Formula doesn't fit, equation number strolls behind (using flalign)

Tags: equations, number, flalign

I have spent some time already trying to fix the way this formula looks, but to no avail. Does anyone have an idea on how to make this look better? Mainly the equation number should fit to the right of the equation.

```
\begin{flalign} \label{eqRWnaRO}
PGW_i =
&\begin{cases}
   PGW_{max},& \text{if } PGW_{i-1} - Q_{PGW,Use}+ MBR_{rec} \ldots \\ &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW} \geq PGW_{max}\\
   0,& \text{if } PGW_{i-1} -  Q_{PGW,Use}+ MBR_{rec} \ldots \\ &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW} \leq 0 \\
   PGW_{i-1} -  Q_{PGW,Use} + MBR_{rec} \ldots \\ \quad *Q_{GW} + RO_{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW},& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}&& 
\end{flalign}
```

[image: The resulting equation]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Do you want the equation number be centred w.r.t. the group?

Comment: please post a complete small document not just a fragment, in particular for this question it is important to know the text width. But as a general comment never use math italic for multi-letter words  use `\mathrm{rec}` or `\mathit{rec}` not  `rec` 9and same for  `Use`, `max` etc

Comment: Hi, I used all the replies with great results! For future reference, how do I see text width? I'm new to the TEX scene.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, using the `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools` at the end of the line which a little too long. I added a variant with a slightly simpler code, using the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath`, since you don't seem to have any alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign} \label{eqRWnaRO}
PGW_i =
&\begin{cases}
   PGW_{\max},& \text{if } PGW_{i-1} - Q_{PGW,Use}+ MBR_\mathrm{rec} \ldots \\
    &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_\mathrm{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW} \geq \mathrlap{PGW_{\max}}\\
   0,& \text{if } PGW_{i-1} - Q_{PGW,Use}+ MBR_\mathrm{rec} \ldots \\
    &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_\mathrm{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW} \leq 0 \\
   PGW_{i-1} - Q_{PGW,Use} + MBR_\mathrm{rec} \ldots \\ \quad *Q_{GW} + RO_\mathrm{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW},& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}&&
\end{flalign}\bigskip

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}
  \label{eqRWnaRO}
PGW_i =
\begin{cases}
   PGW_{\max},& \text{if } PGW_{i-1} - Q_{PGW,Use}+ MBR_\mathrm{rec} \ldots \\
    &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_\mathrm{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW} \geq \mathrlap{PGW_{\max}}\\
   0,& \text{if } PGW_{i-1} - Q_{PGW,Use}+ MBR_\mathrm{rec} \ldots \\
    &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_\mathrm{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW} \leq 0 \\
   PGW_{i-1} - Q_{PGW,Use} + MBR_\mathrm{rec} \ldots \\ \quad *Q_{GW} + RO_\mathrm{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW},& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than feature the repeated expression `PGW_{i-1} - Q_{PGW,Use} + MBR_{rec} \cdot Q_{GW} + RO_{rec}\cdot Q_{RW,PGW}` fully three [3!] times inside a single `cases` environment, I'd give it a name (say, `\theta(PGW_{i-1})`), state it up front, and then simplify the contents of the `cases` environment considerably. (You are obviously free to come up with another function name that `\theta`!) Your readers might appreciate that you made an effort to keep the visual presentation of your material as clutter-free as possible.

In the following code, note the use of the `\vn` macro (short for "variable name", I suppose) to typeset variable names more compactly than if they written out in ordinary math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'cases' environment
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathit{#1}} % typeset variable names

\begin{document}
Put $\theta(\vn{PGW}_{\!i-1})=\vn{PGW}_{\!i-1} - Q_{\vn{PGW},\vn{Use}} 
+ \vn{MBR}_{\vn{rec}} \cdot Q_{\vn{GW}} + \vn{RO}_{\vn{rec}}\cdot Q_{RW,\vn{PGW}}$; 
then,
\begin{equation} \label{eqRWnaRO}
\vn{PGW}_{\!i} =
\begin{cases}
\vn{PGW}_{\!\max} 
  & \text{if }\theta(\vn{PGW}_{\!i-1})\geq\vn{PGW}_{\!\max}\\ 
0 & \text{if }\theta(\vn{PGW}_{\!i-1})\leq 0, \\ 
\theta(\vn{PGW}_{\!i-1})
  & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to guess the line width based on your image, but changes:

avoid math italic for multi-letter names, avoid multi-line constructs like `fleqn` for single line displays, add a `\jot` extra space between the lines of the cases, and I also dropped the commas.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\addtolength\textwidth{72pt}% more or less as shown in question
\begin{document}

aaa
\begin{flalign} \label{eqRWnaRO}
PGW_i =
&\begin{cases}
   PGW_{max},& \text{if } PGW_{i-1} - Q_{PGW,Use}+ MBR_{rec} \ldots \\ &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW} \geq PGW_{max}\\
   0,& \text{if } PGW_{i-1} -  Q_{PGW,Use}+ MBR_{rec} \ldots \\ &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW} \leq 0 \\
   PGW_{i-1} -  Q_{PGW,Use} + MBR_{rec} \ldots \\ \quad *Q_{GW} + RO_{rec}*Q_{RW,PGW},& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}&& 
\end{flalign}

bbb
\begin{equation} \label{eqRWnaROb}
\mathrm{PGW}_i =
\begin{cases}
   \mathrm{PGW}_{\max}& \text{if } \mathrm{PGW}_{i-1} - Q_{\mathrm{PGW},\mathrm{Use}}+ \mathrm{MBR}_{\mathrm{rec}} \ldots \\ &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_{\mathrm{rec}}*Q_{RW,\mathrm{PGW}} \geq \mathrm{PGW}_{\max}\\[\jot]
   0& \text{if } \mathrm{PGW}_{i-1} -  Q_{\mathrm{PGW},\mathrm{Use}}+ \mathrm{MBR}_{\mathrm{rec}} \ldots \\ &\quad *Q_{GW} + RO_{\mathrm{rec}}*Q_{RW,\mathrm{PGW}} \leq 0 \\[\jot]
   \mathrm{PGW}_{i-1} -  Q_{\mathrm{PGW},\mathrm{Use}} + {}\\
   \quad  \mathrm{MBR}_{\mathrm{rec}} \ldots  & \text{otherwise} \\
   \quad *Q_{GW} + RO_{\mathrm{rec}}*Q_{RW,\mathrm{PGW}}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```